# How to Fix this particular "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget." Flutter Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, parent

So I've been looking online answers about this error and always all of them would recommend me to wrap **Expanded** with **Column**, **Flex**, or **Row** . But in my case, it's just not working, here, take a look at my codes

```
Widget _getActionButtons() {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0, top: 45.0),
  child: new Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Flex(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
              child: Container(
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("Cancel"),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.pink[800],
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _status = true;
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                  });
                },
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
              )),
            ),
            flex: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[Here's the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJXRv.png)

I would be very happy if you guys would help me find the culprit of this.. thanks!

Comment: Copy-paste full error messages into the question. **Do not** post them as images.

Comment: Okay, Will do next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well your example works fine with me .. just make sure to call `_getActionButtons()` in a widget that has a specified amount of height otherwise remove the Flex widget.

for example like this

```
Container(height: 200.0,child: _getActionButtons(),) ,
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an expanded widget as the child of a container widget and that is not permitted in Flutter.

An expanded widget should only be direct child of widgets such as Column, Row, ...